# Prevent iPhone charger from capturing audio

Tags: iphone, audio, music

My car has an USB connection which I use to connect to my iPhone 4s (with iOS 7.1) as a charger. But the connection also captures audio, so no sound is emitted from the iphone when the usb wire is connected.

Is there any way to control what's the Iphone behaviour when an external device is switched on, just to avoid the audio to be captured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling a while finally I came up with the solution.
The file /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.iapd.plist seems to track external devices connected to the iphone. If this file is removed, these devices cannot be selected by Airplay.
I'm not sure which are the implication of removing that file and if I restore it, the Airplay functionality would be restored as well, but the fact is it works.
I don't also understand why Apple has not foreseen the possibility of select iphone speakers instead of remote audio even though a dock connector is plugged. Some reason must exist, but it's difficult to understand.
Obviously you need to jailbreak the iphone to remove that file. I simply use a ssh client to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For a solution that doesn't require jailbreaking and modifying your phone's OS, I would suggest a USB charge-only dongle, [like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QRRZ2QM) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FA9GXKM).

Insert that on the USB end of your cable, and it will only connect the charging pins, not the data pins, preventing any audio or other data from transferring.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Control Center for Airplay devices? Normally all Audio capturing devices are listed there. You can check by opening Control Center (swipe up from the bottom) while connected. Now there should be an Airplay Icon and some text "AirPlay". I'm not really sure where exactly it is on an iPhone 4S, I believe somewhere at the bottom. Tap on the icon and you'll get all AirPlay devices connected to the iPhone listed. There select "iPhone" to select the iPhone as the output. I hope I could help,
*GeF*

Comment: there's a single choice under airplay menu called "dock station" when the charger is plugged. no way to unselect it and there's not an "iphone" choice

Comment: Well that's interesting. I don't know then. Please post your solution if you find one by yourself, because I would really like to know.

Comment: Ever find a non-jailbreak solution? When plugging my kids iPad into the car the only option is "Dock Connector" even if the radio is playing in the car. Can't figure out how to disable from the car or the phone.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Docking or cancel, no other options. Like most issues with my iPhone, shutting down fixed it.